# trouble associating tags with entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basic premise of this question is how to make the tags link work so when you click on it, it comes up with all the entries associated with this.

However, when you click on the link, basically, notwithstanding its title, a blank page shows up. It *does not show* the entries associated with its tags.

So clearly the association is not working somewhere? Or the `show` method in Tags controller is not right? Not sure what exactly to fix here.

Here is my code so far: (the section that pertains to the blank page is at the very bottom)

**Entries Controller**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @entries = Entry.all 
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def scrape
    RedditScraper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

**Tags Controller**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all 
  end
    
  def show 
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**Entry Model**

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :link, presence: true

  def tag_list 
    tags.join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(tags_string)
    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
    new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
    self.tags = new_or_found_tags
  end
end
```

**Tag Model**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :entries, through: :taggings

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Tagging Model**

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :entry
end
```

**Entries index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-columns">
        <% @entries.reverse.each do |entry| %>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <p class="card-title"><b><%= entry.title %></b></p>
              <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Tags: <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Tags show.html.erb** (it's this part that doesn't work - i.e., the entries associated with the tag - page shows up as blank)

```
<h1>Entries Tagged with <%= @tag.name %></h1>

<ul>
  <% @tag.entries.each do |entry| %>
    <li><%= link_to entry.title, entry_path(entry) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "All Tags", tags_path %>
```

**Rails Console**

```
e = Entry.first
  Entry Load (28.8ms)  SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries" ORDER BY "entries"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Entry id: 4, title: "Sweet old man at the beach: \"Would you like me to ...", link: "/r/funny/comments/5zut3e/sweet_old_man_at_the_beac...", created_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:25", updated_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:25">
irb(main):036:0> t = Tag.first
  Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Tag id: 3, name: "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/", created_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:26", updated_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:26">
irb(main):037:0> tag.entries
NoMethodError: undefined method `entries' for nil:NilClass
```

**Rails Console 2**

```
irb(main):041:0> tag = Tag.first
  Tag Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Tag id: 3, name: "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/", created_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:26", updated_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:26">
irb(main):042:0> tag.entries << Entry.first
  Entry Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries" ORDER BY "entries"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (32.6ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (318.8ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "entry_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 3], ["entry_id", 4], ["created_at", 2017-03-18 05:05:24 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-18 05:05:24 UTC]]
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Entry Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "entries"."id" = "taggings"."entry_id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1  [["tag_id", 3]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Entry id: 4, title: "Sweet old man at the beach: \"Would you like me to ...", link: "/r/funny/comments/5zut3e/sweet_old_man_at_the_beac...", created_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:25", updated_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:25">]>
irb(main):043:0> tag.save
   (0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true
irb(main):044:0> Tag.first.entries
  Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Entry Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "entries"."id" = "taggings"."entry_id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1  [["tag_id", 3]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Entry id: 4, title: "Sweet old man at the beach: \"Would you like me to ...", link: "/r/funny/comments/5zut3e/sweet_old_man_at_the_beac...", created_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:25", updated_at: "2017-03-17 08:20:25">]>
irb(main):045:0>
```

**rails scraper code**

require 'open-uri'

module RedditScraper

def self.scrape
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

```
entries = doc.css('.entry')
entries.each do |entry|
  title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
  link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
  name = entry.css('p.tagline > a.subreddit')[0]['href']
  Entry.create!(title: title, link: link)
  Tag.create!(name: name)

end
```

end

end

Comment: What's the problem? What are you running into? “Don't know how to X” isn't a great question for StackOverflow to help with without a narrow scope.

Comment: @coreyward, yeah, I know. Sorry for having rambled a bit. Let me clarify the top part of the question a bit ... let me know if it needs to be tweaked further.

Comment: @coreyward, hey, please let me know if this is better? thanks. Happy St. Patrick's day btw!

Comment: Have you got tags and entries set up?  When you do `rails console` you can do `tag = Tag.first` and then when you do `tag.entries` you see the entries in the console?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, when I do `tag = Tag.first`, I get the first entry. When I do `tag.entries`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'entries' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You can't have "tag" contain a valid tag and then "tag.entries" be a `#entries` call on nil.  That suggests `tag` is nil. That (in turn) suggests you have no tags defined in your development database.  Can you do in rails console `Tag.first.name`  and see a name?  Do you then get the same "undefined method" with `Tag.first.entires` ?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn,`Tag.first.name
  Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/"`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, `Tag.first.entries
  Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Entry Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "entries"."id" = "taggings"."entry_id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1  [["tag_id", 3]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, I'm super puzzled as well as much my understanding goes

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Earlier one that you had requested - in post above at bottom

Comment: Ok, that first tag has no entries so the colleciton proxy is an empty array `[]`.  Now try assigning an entry manually.  `tag = Tag.first; tag.entries << Entry.first; tag.save`  and then try `Tag.first.entries` again and this time you should see an array returned with the entry.  (This assumes you have an entry in your `entries` table)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, just did it right now. It's underneath `Rails Console 2` in above's post ... and yes, there is an array returned with the entry (and yes, `entries` table has `entry` column)

Comment: So now that you've added something to the tag, does the view now work?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, finally got a chance to do it right now ... and yes, the view works for the first one. How do I fix this so this applies to all the tags? And thank you, btw.

Comment: You should post another question.  Clearly the problem now is that tags aren't being associated with entries or vice versa.  The problem is in your tags/entries form and/or your TagsController/FormsController create or update methods.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, ok, so create another question with the title that reflects the fact that it's the `Tags Controller` that's problematic since it's not associating the tags with the entries?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, are you sure you don't want post an answer here? Since clearly you understand what's the problem here and how to fix it ...?

Comment: At what point is the tag supposed to be associated with an entry?  Is it when you add an entry or update an entry?  In that case, the EntriesController and/or entries/_form are wrong. Maybe show the full EntriesController including the entry_params method.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, that is my entire EntriesController. I've included at bottom the scraper code where the entries and tags are getting their information from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scraper code to build the association.

Instead of...

```
  Entry.create!(title: title, link: link)
  Tag.create!(name: name)
```

Do...

```
  entry = Entry.create!(title: title, link: link)
  tag = Tag.create!(name: name)
  tag.entries << entry
  tag.save!
```

Comment: @SteveTurxzyn, would you mind also including the conventional show action this would be if it were a typical ROR project instead of scrapped project? Maybe that could fix it? Then the assoication can be in Tag's show action above? Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, sorry, edited my answer. I wrote it originally for a one-to-one but of course it's many-to-many