# Problematic Tags Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two three models of which two are `:through association`.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to have all the entries show up when associated with a particular tag.

The entries themselves show up on the index page as so do the tags. When you click on the tag, it basically shows a blank page.

Originally, I thought the problem was that the tags are not associated with the entries and have that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866446/trouble-associating-tags-with-entries?noredirect=1#comment72883641_42866446). I've been told otherwise, and to create a new question.

Please help me to understand what is going on here so I can fix this and make it work.

Thank you.

**Scrapped Data**

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper

  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      name = entry.css('p.tagline > a.subreddit')[0]['href']
      Entry.create!(title: title, link: link)
      Tag.create!(name: name)

    end
  end

end
```

**Tagging Model**

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :entry
end
```

**Tag Model**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :entries, through: :taggings

    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Entry Model**

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings


    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :link, presence: true

    def tag_list 
        tags.join(", ")
    end

    def tag_list=(tags_string)
  tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
  new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
  self.tags = new_or_found_tags
end

end
```

**Entries Controller**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

    def index 
        @entries = Entry.all 
        @tags = Tag.all
    end

  def show
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  end

    def scrape

    RedditScrapper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

**Tags Controller** (Part 1 - where I think the problem resides)

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @tags = Tag.all 
    end

    def show 
        @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

This is the Entries' `index.html.erb` page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-columns">
            <% @entries.reverse.each do |entry| %>
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <p class="card-title"><b><%= entry.title %></b></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
   <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= @tags.class %>
    <p>Tags: <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
    <% end %>
</div>

</div>
```

**Tag's `show.html.erb`** (part two of the other problem, I think)

```
<h1>Entries Tagged with <%= @tag.name %></h1>

<ul>
  <% @tag.entries.each do |entry| %>
    <li><%= link_to entry.title, entry_path(entry) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "All Tags", tags_path %>
```

Comment: can you open rails c to see that there are entries for the tag? You're not showing how taggings/entries are created, and if there are none then the index will be empty.

Comment: Entries model... `tags.join ','`... Are you joining rows? Shouldn't you map names first?

Comment: @maxple, the information is being scrapped, hence why no form. Have added the scrapped code in `Scrapped Data` section above.

Comment: @RubyRacer, honestly, I'm not entirely sure what that does. It's from a tutorial for tagging. Was trying to make the tagging stuff work.

Comment: You are not creating taggings in your scraper

Comment: @maxple, how do I do that?

Comment: Tagging.create and pass that tag and entry ids

Comment: @maxple, would you mind making that an answer so I can see what you're talking about? Or were you talking about something like this: `Tagging.create!(name: name_id, entry: entry_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scraper method you have this:

```
  Entry.create!(title: title, link: link)
  Tag.create!(name: name)
```

remember that wit your association setup, a entry is only linked to a tag *through* a tagging. Which you're not creating.

Just do this:

```
  entry = Entry.create!(title: title, link: link)
  tag = Tag.create!(name: name)
  Tagging.create(entry_id: entry.id, tag_id: tag.id)
```